# SIGPIPE crash when switching background task

Tags: iphone, ipad, crash, background-process, sigpipe

I'm experiencing a weird crash when sending my app into the background, loading a new app, switching the device into sleep mode, waking up the device, closing the new app and then opening my app from the background tasks. A black screen will appear and I cannot exit this black screen with the home button, and in the debugger I am shown this message:

> Program received signal:  “SIGPIPE”.
>   Data Formatters unavailable (Error
>   calling dlopen for:
>   "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib":
>   "dlopen(/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib,
>   10): no suitable image found.  Did
>   find:
>   /Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib:
>   out of address space
>   /Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib:
>   stat() failed with errno=868226285

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

Set `SO_NOSIGPIPE` on your socket via `setsockopt()`, or ignore all `SIGPIPE` signals with:
`signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)`.

Comment: Using `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)`, the Xcode debugger may still halt with the SIGPIPE signal. In that case, just press the Continue button and Xcode will happily ignore the SIGPIPE.